# samhain troubleshooting and performance

Tags: security, monitoring

I am new user to Samhain so don't know much about it except the fact why its used. Now I am finding my samhain-2.8.5 is consuming too much of CPU. Its almost eating up 2 cores and I cant find the reason. I tried little bit googling but it does not seems to help me when it comes to troubleshoot this problem.

In samhain logs all I could find is

```
3277BD028C279FC54B43E656BB3EA8E17A50136FF56B2085
MARK   :  [2012-11-01T14:58:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
DB1F18F7BF0118EA2A0A2E3CE0F227306AA2240F7D415D86
MARK   :  [2012-11-01T14:59:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
CB231517356010B7491CB428D7A83FCEE60A1FE4D829286A
MARK   :  [2012-11-01T15:00:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
C2911B37C38C028B707E7B0ECA96B22495A19853A53D9D10
MARK   :  [2012-11-01T15:01:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
7C33C05ACD870F9C866BAF73F33A9AF6A53937ADA3093425
MARK   :  [2012-11-01T15:02:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
5E45F7AF951EF082D4D1E0F4C8122543FBE247A9C231D75F
MARK   :  [2012-11-01T15:03:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
9A534980763124616000F1B9206A15825019F31E5E5746E3
MARK   :  [2012-11-01T15:04:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
E01DFCE3D446CE7471480A0620A65371043E283E9EC2EF6C
MARK   :  [2012-11-01T15:05:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
66B3BDCE9B0003BBC852DFD26D65338E1B1AEF657BECE076
MARK   :  [2012-11-01T15:06:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
4B8B1419285EFA450F38B6C11FF9DE33BD9294F8B9DF4ECC
MARK   :  [2012-11-01T15:07:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
093D24204088E3132B53D0158F4213DB9752282D21491F3B
```

Appreciate any input in this regard. The server is in production.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. It was signing issue that lead to such a performance hit. Not sure weather newer versions have some means to inform end users.

What I suspect is the samhain binary and the samhainrc/samhain_file were not signed properly or with the same key and that made samhain go crazy eating whole CPU.

Other than this there is no other reason why in one installation (some other guy did) it works and and new installation (which I did) does not.

It might help in some cases, but not all. I resigned it but the issue reappear.